# Що означає слово "гарап"?

Tags: значення-слів, іменники

У [Записках наукового товариства імені Шевченка](http://shron2.chtyvo.org.ua/Naukove_tovarystvo_imeni_Shevchenka/Zapysky_Tom_088.pdf) (с. 158) натрапила на таке речення:

> [...] а ґазду бив **гарапом**.

Не знаю, що означає виділене слово. [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/gharap) його не подає.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В [Словнику української мови за ред. Б. Грінченка](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/8777-gharapa.html) знаходжу значення цього слова:

> **Гарапа,** -пи, ж. = *гарапник*. Драг. 277.

Далі за [посиланням](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA):

> **Гарапник,** ка, м. Плеть, арапникъ. Рудч. Ск. II. 183. Шух. І. 292. Гарапник тройчатий. Г. Арт. (О. 1861. ІІІ. 105).

У [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/gharapnyk) також знаходимо значення цього слова:

> **ГАРА́ПНИК,** а, чол. Довгий батіг, сплетений з тонких ремінців.

Answer (score 4):

Знаходимо також це слово у [Словнику лемківської говірки](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/2131/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF), де воно означає: "Батіг з короткою ручкою і довгим ремінцем". І варто погодитися, що це радше "**гарапа**", а не "гарап", бо останнє має значення: "*васт. Негр. І перевізчик тут явився, ..Од сонця ввесь він попалився І губи, як арап, оддув (Котл., І, 1952, 130)*" ([джерело](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BF)), тобто це людина із чорною або смуглою шкірою.

Comment: Хм.... подивився - дійсно мало значення і негр також, прийшло через Турецьку мову коли османи в арабів рабів купували (в основному чорних, але не тільки...)